# upload large file failed via express+multer

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer, large-files

I tired to uplaod a **7G tar file** to my server (via postman) but failed.

I tried to upload same file several times, and **my server only recieved 2.8G everytime (spend about 12-15 minutes)** then postman's request got some error like `read ECONNRESET`, `write EPIPE`.

And my server got an error `Unexpected end of multipart data`, this error is evoked by `multer` package.

### what I have tried?

- After google the errors, it seems like the problem of `connection between client and server disrupt`
- I also tried to upload a 3.5G video (because server only recived 2.8G in my question), then it **succeed** and **spend 19 minutes**!!
- Then I tar that 3.5G video, and upload it again. Also succeed!

### My summary and How can I do?

In beginning, I think the problem is about `request timeout`, `upload directory storage limit`, `tar file limitation` or `multer package problem`.

- But upload the video (and its tar file) spend more than 12-15 minutes, so it seems not the timeout problem. And also not the tar file problem.
- And the 3.5G video (and its tar file) can be saved in the directory, so it is not the storage limitation problem.
- I **execute same code in macOS**, and it can uplaod that 7G file!! So, it seems not the problem about multer package.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Anyone can help me?

#### My code

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const http = require('http')

const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)

const PORT = 5568
const uploader = multer({ dest: '/tmp' }).single('file')

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  uploader(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('errrrrr');
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).json(err)
    }

    console.log('upload finish!!!')
    return res.status(200).json(req.file)
  })
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(server is running at ${PORT} ...)
})
```